# Refactor multiple triggers into one

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to reduce this to a single trigger?

```
<Style x:Key="StatusTextBlock" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Running">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Paused">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Stopped">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `"Running"` and `"Stopped"` are the only two available cases, you can set one as a property, and only use one trigger:

```
<Style x:Key="StatusTextBlock" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" /> <!--default case == Running -->
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Stopped">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: @O.O In that case, you need them all, or switch to use VisualStateManager.